# Automator App to Send Print Job at Specified Time

Tags: macos, automator

I need a way to have a Mac send a print job at 8:30 every morning. Our copier takes FOREVER to wake up, and we'd like to have it warm and ready to go when we walk in. Automator is ideal, but any solution that's feasible for a non-developer is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can easily be done with Automator.

1. Create an empty document and save it (somewhere you won't move it)
2. Open Automator and create a new **Calendar Alarm** workflow
3. Drag in the **Get Specified Finder Items** into the workflow
4. Add the empty document you just created
5. Drag in the **Print Finder Items**
6. Select the printer you want
7. Save the workflow. Calendar will open
8. Edit the new Calendar entry

   - Select the time you want the workflow to start
   - Put repeat on every day or a custom repeat (only office days)

*Note: Your Mac needs to be on and you need to be logged in.*

Comment: Thank you! A variation of this has been working beautifully for months. Now though, we'd like to move away from one static, locally-stored PDF that's printed every morning to a webpage, and SPECIFICALLY to a webpage in Safari's Reader view. Our goal here is to print the week's horoscopes, but without all the browser garbage that one would get if printing the native webpage.

Comment: Alternatively, we're open to printing an _online_ PDF, such as the NYT's print edition. But such a PDF has a URL that changes frequently, so we'd need a way to parse the NYT site for said link, upon auto-print.